# Qt QTableView - Alignment of checkbox when using IsUserCheckable

Tags: qt, checkbox, alignment

I am using QTableView's checkbox flag of *Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable* to display a checkbox in a table cell.

After reading some things on alignment in an attempt to center the checkbox within the cell, I am returning the *Qt::AlignCenter* as the TextAlignmentRole  from the models data() function.

```
QVariant ExampleModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const 
{
  if(!index.isValid())
     return QVariant();

  if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole) 
       return Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter;
}
```

This however is not aligning my checkbox.

Does anyone know how to align checkboxes is this mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further investigation into delegate options I found a nice reference (unfortunately no longer available) and came up with the following hybrid using a QItemDelegate and IsUserCheckable.

Essentially, you need to extend QItemDelegate, and reimplement, using the *drawCheck* function to center and use the `editorEvent` to handle mouse and keyboard events while setting the model with the appropriate state.

```
void drawCheck(QPainter* painter, QStyleOptionViewItem const& option, QRect const& rect, Qt::CheckState state) const
```

and

```
bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
```

Also see this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785434/how-to-interact-with-checkbox-actions-qtableview-with-qstandarditemmodel/4451324#4451324)...

Comment: 2 of the links are broken

Answer (score 4):

Solution for Python (PySide, PyQt) to center the checkbox and with editable allowed:

```
class BooleanDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BooleanDelegate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        # Depends on how the data function of your table model is implemented
        # 'value' should recive a bool indicate if the checked value.
        value = index.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)  
        self.drawCheck(painter, option, option.rect, value)
        self.drawFocus(painter, option, option.rect)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            value = bool(model.data(index, Qt.CheckStateRole))
            model.setData(index, not value)
            event.accept()
        return super(BooleanDelegate, self).editorEvent(event, model, option, index)
```

In your table model, make sure that the flags allow the user to check/uncheck the cell.

```
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    ...

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.column() in self.columns_boolean:
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
        return Qt.ItemFlags(QAbstractTableModel.flags(self, index) | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

Finally, set the `BooleanDelagate` in your table

```
self.boolean_delegate = BooleanDelegate()
self.input_gui.setItemDelegateForColumn(5, self.boolean_delegate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, however I found it much easier to implement my own checkbox item delegate when using qtableviews.

Answer (score 2):

TextAlignmentRole really does mean what it says. Unfortunately, as you probably noticed, there doesn't seem to be any Icon/Widget alignment role available at all.

Bug report: http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9047

Same question with some answers: http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-06/msg00476.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with. This is assuming that you want the checkbox to be the only thing in the cell.

```
class CenteredCheckboxDelegate final : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;

    void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & o, const QModelIndex & index ) const override
    {
        auto option2 = o;
        initStyleOption(&option2, index);

        auto * widget = option2.widget;
        auto * style = widget ? widget->style() : QApplication::style();

        // Turn off all features and just draw the background
        option2.state.setFlag(QStyle::State_HasFocus, false);
        option2.features.setFlag(QStyleOptionViewItem::HasDisplay, false);
        option2.features.setFlag(QStyleOptionViewItem::HasDecoration, false);
        option2.features.setFlag(QStyleOptionViewItem::HasCheckIndicator, false);
        style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &option2, painter, widget);

        // Then just draw the a checkbox centred in the cell
        option2.rect = getCheckboxRect(option2);
        auto stateFlag = option2.checkState == Qt::Checked ? QStyle::State_On : QStyle::State_Off;
        option2.state.setFlag(stateFlag, true);
        style->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorViewItemCheck, &option2, painter, widget);
    }

    bool editorEvent(QEvent * event, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) override
    {
        auto flags = index.flags();
        if (!flags.testFlag(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable) || !flags.testFlag(Qt::ItemIsEnabled))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        {
            auto * mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            bool mouseOverCheckbox = getCheckboxRect(option).contains(mouseEvent->pos());
            if(!mouseOverCheckbox) return false;
        }
        else if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            auto * keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
            if(keyEvent->key() != Qt::Key_Space) return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        auto checkState = index.data(Qt::CheckStateRole).value<Qt::CheckState>();
        auto toggledCheckState = checkState == Qt::Checked ? Qt::Unchecked : Qt::Checked;
        return model->setData(index, toggledCheckState, Qt::CheckStateRole);
    }

private:
    QRect getCheckboxRect(const QStyleOptionViewItem & option) const
    {
        auto * widget = option.widget;
        auto * style = widget ? widget->style() : QApplication::style();
        auto checkboxSize = style->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_CheckBoxIndicator, &option, widget).size();
        return QStyle::alignedRect(option.direction, Qt::AlignCenter, checkboxSize, option.rect);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can look at this thread:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/19157-QTableView-checkbox-center-with-stylesheet?p=181413#post181413

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 / Pyside2 Version, based on the amazing C++ version of Parker Coates

```
class QTableviewEditableDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

def __init__(self, alignment: Qt.Alignment, parent: Optional[QWidget] = None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.alignment: Qt.Alignment = alignment
    self.parent = parent

    if self.parent:
        self.style = self.parent.style()
    else:
        self.style = QApplication.style()

def editorEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent, model: QAbstractItemModel, option: QStyleOptionViewItem,
                index: QModelIndex) -> bool:
    checkbox_data = index.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
    flags = index.flags()
    if not (flags & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable) or not (flags & Qt.ItemIsEnabled) or checkbox_data is None:
        return False
    else:
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            mouseover_checkbox: bool = self.get_checkbox_rect(option).contains(event.pos())
            if not mouseover_checkbox:
                return False
        elif event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() != Qt.Key_Space:
            return False
        else:
            return False
        if checkbox_data == Qt.Checked:
            checkbox_toggled: int = Qt.Unchecked
        else:
            checkbox_toggled: int = Qt.Checked
        return model.setData(index, checkbox_toggled, Qt.CheckStateRole)

def get_checkbox_rect(self, option: QStyleOptionViewItem) -> QRect:
    widget = option.widget
    if widget:
        style = widget.style()
    else:
        style = self.style()
    checkbox_size: QSize = style.subElementRect(QStyle.SE_CheckBoxIndicator, option, widget).size()
    return QStyle.alignedRect(option.direction, Qt.AlignCenter, checkbox_size, option.rect)

def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QModelIndex):
    try:
        self.initStyleOption(option, index)
        painter.save()

        flags: Qt.ItemFlags = index.model().flags(index)
        widget: Optional[QWidget] = option.widget
        checkbox_data = index.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if widget:
            style = widget.style()
        else:
            style = self.style()

        if option.HasCheckIndicator and checkbox_data is not None:
            option_checkbox = option
            self.initStyleOption(option_checkbox, index)
            option_checkbox.state = option_checkbox.state & ~QStyle.State_HasFocus
            option_checkbox.features = option_checkbox.features & ~QStyleOptionViewItem.HasDisplay
            option_checkbox.features = option_checkbox.features & ~QStyleOptionViewItem.HasDecoration
            option_checkbox.features = option_checkbox.features & ~QStyleOptionViewItem.HasCheckIndicator
            style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option_checkbox, painter, widget)

            # Then just draw the a checkbox centred in the cell
            option_checkbox.rect = self.get_checkbox_rect(option_checkbox)
            if option_checkbox.checkState == Qt.Checked:
                state_flag = QStyle.State_On
            else:
                state_flag = QStyle.State_Off

            option_checkbox.state = option_checkbox.state | state_flag
            style.drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_IndicatorViewItemCheck, option_checkbox, painter, widget)

        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
       
        painter.restore()

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```