# Qt4 QTableView and checkbox click event

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4, qt-creator

I have created `QTableView` and add an `QStandardItem` checkbox into with this code:

```
....
QStandardItem *chkItem = new QStandardItem(true);
chkItem->setCheckable(true);
chkItem->setData(Qt::AlignCenter, Qt::TextAlignmentRole);
tblModel->appendRow(chkItem);
...
```

where `tblModel` is `QStandardItemModel`.

Now i wonder how can i catch the checkbox changed state event?

I have tryed catch the table click event but this is triggered every times user click on a cell (i have no idea to know whether the checkbox state has changed or not). Please give me a way to solve this problem.

Comment: This should answer it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785434/how-to-interact-with-checkbox-actions-qtableview-with-qstandarditemmodel?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try `QStandardItem::checkState()` to retrieve the `Qt::CheckState` of the checkbox. If you need to know, if the state changed, then save the old state somewhere and check if the state changed on the click event.

Comment: But in QTableView click event i don't know whether the checkbox state have changed or not